# Blocky Textures around object, Blender render artifacts, possible causes?

Tags: rendering, texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, artifacts

I'm getting weird render artifacts around the edge of a cylinder on the floor, blocky areas that look low-res:

[image: Blocky Texture Renders]
(Edit) Image A: Blocky Textures behind the cylinder

Rendering from other angles shows the same render artifacts. Seemingly around the render box intersecting both the cylinder and floor.

I've tried changing anti-aliasing and other settings with no effect.

[image: Outliner and Render Settings]
(Edit) Image B: Outliner, Viewport, and Render Settings

I'm at a loss. Any ideas?

Other Info:
   Blender v2.76. 
   Blender Render.
   This floor texture is rather large, 12.3 MB file and 4288 x 2848.
   But artifacts happen with other (smaller) textures as well.

Comment: You can use Blender or GIMP to create images that show more information to solve your problem ... multiple screen shots combined into one picture.  I suggest you do that.  Please show your outliner window to determine if there are more objects in the scene.

Comment: Check to see if in the Post Processing Panel for the Camera you are using the Compositor or VSE.  If so turn them both off temporarily.

Comment: Good idea, I've updated the images.

I turned off Compositing and Sequencer in the Post Processing in Render Settings and no effect.

Comment: Strange, creating a new cylinder and rendering that clears the artifacts. The issue must be in the original mesh data somehow. I'll let you know if I pin it down. In the meantime, here's the render with the fresh new cylinder: [link](http://s16.postimg.org/gsxg8i2qd/Cylinder_new_Render_fix.png)

Comment: The artifacts are back. It happens at some point when I start unwrapping the object (marking seams, unwrapping, etc.) I wonder how unwrapping can cause this. [link](http://s12.postimg.org/cmkvhywuz/Brick_Texture_Blocky_A.png)

Comment: Deleting the UV Map from the Data panel clears the artifacts. Opened a new file and applied textures and UV Map and get artifacts again.

Comment: Could you share the .blend file?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was: assigning a UV Map to the Cylinder was somehow messing up the floor's texture or UV Map. I don't know why. But I was able to clear the artifacts from the render:

I fixed it by selecting the floor --> Edit Mode, and applying a UV Map to it, via the left panel (Shading / UVs tab) --> UVs section --> Unwrap. So both the Cylinder and floor have their own UV Maps.

[image: Unwrap the Floor]

I don't know why changing the cylinder created artifacts on the floor; they are two different objects, two different UV Maps, two different materials, two different textures. But this solution worked for me!

[image: Final Image with correct textures and no artifacts]